# display mobile number in create an account page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I want to display mobile number in create an account page in **Magento 2**.

Iam editing below page with following code but it include address also in my create an account page, I just want telephone number attribute.

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
        <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: did you enable Stores -> Configuration Customer -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Adress options -> Show Telephone

Answer (score 1):

1/ You need to create a mobilePhone attribute

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install data
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * CustomerSetupFactory
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * $attributeSetFactory
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * initiate object
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * install data method
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_phone', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mobile phone',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_phone')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                /*use this mobile phone attribute in the all bellow forms*/
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout', 'checkout_register'],

            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

2/

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Then add your custom attribute as something like this:

```
<div class="field phone required">
    <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="telephone" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getMobilePhone()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Mobile Phone')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-mobilePhoneNumber':true}">
     </div>
 </div>
```